# How much companionship exp do I need per rank?

Tags: genshin-impact

Is there a way to see exactly how much current companionship/friendship exp I have with one character and how much I need to reach the next level?

Comment: In recent patch they did some UI improvements, hopefully they will improve friendship UI at some point. There is an achievement to get several character to level 10 of friendship, my main party has barely got 5 each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there is currently no official data nor is it printed in anywhere in the game, it is impossible to know the exact amounts.

However, we can approximate it by counting the number of pixels the bar has filled after we gain companionship experience.

```
| Companionship Level   | Experience needed     | Cumulative Experience     |
|---------------------  |-------------------    |-----------------------    |
| 2                     | 1000                  | 1000                      |
| 3                     | 1500                  | 2500                      |
| 4                     | 2000                  | 4500                      |
| 5                     | 2600                  | 7100                      |
| 6                     | 3200                  | 10300                     |
| 7                     | 3800                  | 14100                     |
| 8                     | 4400                  | 18500                     |
| 9                     | 5200                  | 23700                     |
| 10                    | 6000                  | 29700                     |
```

[Source](https://bbs.mihoyo.com/ys/article/2822584)